# The Sign of the Direction of Motion & Difficulty of the Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I was trying to solve the following question

> A particle moves in a straight line experiencing an acceleration equal to $\frac{2}{x^2}$ towards the origin. If the particle starts from rest at a distance $4$ units from the origin, show that the time it takes to reach the origin is $2\pi$

**Context**
I placed the particle on the left of the origin, and said that it was moving towards the origin from there i.e. direction towards origin is positive. I said how its direction of motion is positive, and thus its acceleration is also positive (in this scenario). I proceeded from there as follows;

$$\ddot x=\frac{2}{x^2}=v\frac{dv}{dx} $$

As initially ($t=0$) $v=0$ (at rest) $x=-4$ (distance from origin), I evaluate the following;
$$\int_0^v vdv = 2\int_{-4}^x \frac{dx}{x^2}$$
Solving, and rearranging
$$v^2 = \frac{-x-4}{x}$$
$$\therefore v=+\sqrt{\frac{-x-4}{x}}$$
(As the velocity is towards the origin, which I said was positve, velocity is then positive).

As $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, I rearrange the obtain the following integral (Note: at $x=-4, t=0$ and $x=0, t=T_1$ (desired time));
$$\int_{-4}^0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{-x-4}}dx = \int_0^{T_1} dt$$

Though I currently don't know of any method to easily solve the integral on the right hand side. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20((x)%5E0.5%20%2F%20(-x-4)%5E0.5)%20from%20x%3D-4%20to%20x%3D0) evaluates it as $2\pi$, but regardless I don't know how to easily solve the integral.

**BUT**

If I defined the motion of the particle as negative (then acceleration is negative) i.e. direction away from origin positive, I eventually obtain the following integral;
$$\int_{4}^0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}dx = - \int_0^{T_1} dt$$

Which can easily be solved through a simple trigonometric substitution.

**The Question**
Why does changing the direction which is considered positive, DRAMATICALLY effect the difficulty of the integral to be evaluated?
For motion questions (or maybe just in general), how would I know beforehand which direction to make positive, so as to eliminate the need to evaluate a more complicated integral in trade for a much more simplistic one (as above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look again at the integral
$$\int_{-4}^0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{-x-4}}dx.$$

Do you see what's wrong with it? 
You're integrating over $x \in [-4,0],$ but the integrand isn't defined
anywhere in that interval: $-x-4 < 0$ when $x \leq 0,$ and you can't take the square root of a negative number (at least not in real analysis).

Let's try it again. Presumably, you got that integral by substituting
$v=\sqrt{\frac{-x-4}{x}}$ in the integral 
$\int_{-4}^0 \frac{dx}{v}.$
That is,
$$\int_{-4}^0 \frac{dx}{v} = \int_{-4}^0 \sqrt{\frac{x}{-x-4}}\,dx.$$

This is fine, because dividing a negative by a negative gives you a positive number, and you can take the square root of a positive number.
In order to rewrite $\sqrt{\frac ab}$ as $\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b},$
however, $a$ must be non-negative and $b$ must be positive.
So let's make them so:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{x}{-x-4}} = \sqrt{\frac{-x}{x+4}}
= \frac{\sqrt{-x}}{\sqrt{4+x}}.$$
Note that for $-4 < x < 0,$ both $-x$ and $4+x$ are positive,
so these equations are correct.

So now you can write
$$
\int_{-4}^0 \sqrt{\frac{x}{-x-4}}\,dx 
= \int_{-4}^0 \frac{\sqrt{-x}}{\sqrt{4+x}}\,dx
= -\int_4^0 \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{4-u}}\,du
$$
with the substitution $u = -x,$ and you have your "easy" integral.